# How do I get the C# TypeCode of an IBuffer?

Tags: c#

How do I get the C# TypeCode of an IBuffer's data? IBuffer.GetType always returns TypeCode object but the data in my IBuffer contains a byte array.

Comment: What you ask does not exist. `TypeCode` is an enum, with limited fields mapping to known types.. `Object` member is there just as a placeholder for any class that is not known in advance. You probably need something else (some other type of key). What are you trying to do with the `TypeCode` value?

Comment: Given an IBuffer I am trying to find out what kind of data it represents. For example, if an IBuffer contains an array of bytes it would be sufficient to know that the IBuffer contains a TypeCode of Byte since using IBuffer.Length would tell me how many bytes are contains in the IBuffer. So I am trying to find out if it is possible to somehow find the TypeCode for an IBuffer's data.

Comment: What is the full name of the `IBuffer` interface you are using? If you mean [IBuffer Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.ibuffer), then you are out of luck, because the documentation clearly states that it is a buffer of bytes (always, only bytes), with no knowledge of what such bytes represent. Obviously, it can be implemented by a more specialized class that wraps the bytes to convey some more meaningful data type, but the interface itself does not.

Comment: Head Slap! It helps to really read the documentation... Thanks for the reminder.